# Print only one element with @media print using react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am having a little drag and drop  game, this game has a how-to-play button that opens a modal with text and guides with it, when I click to print( real-life print) I want to show only that one element nothing else. That's where I need your help.

I tried to do this with CSS:

```
@media print {
  body {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .modal-window {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Thought this would help but this shows me only a blank page,somehow I need to print only the my Modal.js element which has a div with a class of .modal-window.

If I open the modal (click to the howtoplay button) I get it right, but my task is to do this without clicking on that button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding body. Your modal window element is in body so it's hidden as well.

Try hiding everything in body except modal window

```
body *{
    visibility:hidden;
}

body .modal-window {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: that should work but how do I achieve the thing where I don't need to click on the howtoplay button? I just kinda need to get to my page go to print and it prints only the one element in my case my modal .